# Panels added via Panelizer are deleted after going to node/edit and saving the node

Tags: panels

I create an article and then "Customize this page" and add a panel to the page. I can re-save that page using panelizer over and over again with no issues. However, when I go into the "new draft" page and edit and publish the node, all items that were added with panelizer are removed from the article.

Very similar to this https://drupal.org/node/1572202 with the difference being that I notice it happens when I save from the node/edit page. I already have the patch on that page applied because it was added to the latest version of panelizer which I have.